# Where to obtain the apache JavaHL subversion binding library?

Tags: java, apache, svn, javahl

I can find the API-docs for JavaHL 1.6 at http://subversion.apache.org/docs/javahl/1.6/ . However I can't find any pointer to a jar+native binary (win32) package, or maven resource. Where do you obtain these artifacts?

Comment: I'm also looking for this. Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems no obvious way to retrieve them directly (searched in some Maven repos). JavaHL (win32) is part every current eclipse version with subversive in it. So technically, the following would work:

- Install in a fresh Eclipse installation the plugin `Subversive`.
- Include there the (optional) library JavaHL.
- At the end, you will find the library files in the directory `plugins/org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl16.win32_<version-nr>`

Perhaps this workaround helps you, but I am interested in the "real" solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WANDisco SVN client installation, which installs the native libraries and 'paired' JAR file. See the accepted answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782416), which I'm going to suggest this as a duplicate of. (Although this question is older, I think the answer to the later one is more correct, so I see it as better that this is a duplicate of that if it makes any difference!)