# Paired JAR and native library binaries for SVN Java bindings (JavaHL) on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, svn, javahl

I'm writing some code that uses the Subversion (SVN) Java bindings (JavaHL) directly (where JavaHL comprises native libraries and a thin Java wrapper). On Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) this is no problem: package `libsvn-java` installs the native libraries and `\usr\share\java\svn-javahl.jar`, so i just reference the latter and away I go.

On Windows, I know of no such clean packaging of the pair (JAR + native libraries) together. I was aware that SlikSVN contains a JavaHL implementation, but installing that seems only to install the *native libraries* (which it does put on the PATH). Is there anything that gives a clean package of the two? (If SlikSVN *does* package the JAR, it's in no place I expect, and a search of the whole drive finds nothing...)

As a workaround, I built the JAR file manually (details below which may be useful for people). But it seems that the 'match' of Java wrapper and native libraries is very precise: when I built a JAR from later SVN source code (instead of that matching my exact SlikSVN SVN version) as a test, I got fatal errors in the native code (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION). Perhaps I was unlucky but, if it is pretty sensitive, I'll need to provide a JAR library for every potential version of SlikSVN (and thus SVN) that users might install (or restrict their SlikSVN choices, or have some prone-to-error auto-build process which would need them to install a JDK). All bad options :-(

### Manual Workaround (Bad!)

I had SlikSVN 1.8.10: `svn --version` reports version `1.8.10-SlikSvn-1.8.10-X64`.

So I got the Java wrapper source from the tagged SVN release. (You can also get it from the 
[main site's source downloads](https://subversion.apache.org/download).)

```
svn export http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.10/subversion/bindings/javahl/src
```

Compiling this (there are no dependencies) into a JAR, and using that, worked fine with the SlikSVN native libraries.

P.S. I know that I could use SVNKit to avoid having to do this, but I'm doing this precisely so as *not* to rely on SVNKit for licensing reasons (plus the JavaHL API is fine and reasonably high-level anyway, and there are other reasons to prefer using the 'official' native JavaHL implementation).

Answer (score 1):

The WANdisco binaries should have JavaHL in them.

http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download

Been a while since I used them myself (don't typically use Windows).  But WANdisco has tools that depend on JavaHL so I can't imagine the Windows binaries are missing JavaHL.

**[Question author edit to complete detail]**

You need to install the (Windows) Subversion client (**not** SmartSVN), and make sure you check the box to add it to the Windows `PATH`. This stores the 'paired' JAR in the install directory (along with the native libraries). **However**, WANDisco only provide a 32-bit install (see this [forum post](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/69252-Subversion-command-line-client-64bit-version-for-Windows)) so this won't work on 64-bit Windows. In addition, the JAR only includes the Apache versions of the API, which were added for Subversion 1.7. If you're using the legacy `org.tigris.subversion.javahl` package API for compatibility with pre-1.7 SVN clients, you still need to build the JAR manually.

Comment: Thanks also to Branko Čibej, who suggested the same on the Subversion mailing lists.

Comment: Now unaccepting this answer because of the 32-bit only issue. CollabNet SVN clients also include JavaHL (x32 and x64) but, as with SlikSVN, without the 'paired' JAR file.